# Sort Macro with dynamic range and customOrder excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a multi-level sort Macro, while the amount of rows is dynamic. I've been messing around with some test data to try and get it to work, however I keep getting 1004 run-time errors from Excel. Hoping a second pair of eyes will help figure this out.

Here is the test data

```
A       B        C      D
Num Status  Junk    Junk
1   Open    1       1
2   Open    2       2
3   Closed  3       3
3   Open    3       3
4   Open    4       4
6   Open    6       6
8   Open    8       8
8   Open    8       8
34  Open    34      34
456 Open    456     456
5   Closed  5       5
853 Open    853     853
2345Closed  2345    2345
234 Open    234     234
23  Closed  23      23
4   Open    4       4
76  Closed  76      76
345 Open    345     345
623 Closed  623     623
523 Open    523     523
4525Closed  4525    4525
6   Open    6       6
```

And here is my Macro

```
Range("A1:D1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("B1:B10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "Open,Closed", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("A1:A10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Also see the Line where i have Range("A1:A10"), want A10 to be the last row. So I was unsure what to put there.

Thanks all,

Jim

Comment: The Excel error 1004 means that your VBA code threw an error, but you neglected to catch it with an Error Handler.  You should ***always*** have an error-hanlder in Excel VBA, to avoid this and many other problems!.  Put in an `ON ERROR ...` statement, and then a statement like `MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly` in the error handler to see what your actual error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your last row into a variable, then use that variable in your range name, like I've done below. I've also cleaned up your code a bit to make it easier to read and more efficient. You were getting Run-Time error, because you were missing the `SetRange` method:

```
Sub mySort()

Dim lngLast As Long
lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Go to Whoa! 'in honor of Siddhart Rout (I like that :))
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "Open,Closed", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A1" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A1:D" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

On Error Go To 0
Exit Sub

Whoa!:
    Msgbox "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbOkOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Good, but Excel VBA external entry points should always have an error-handler.

Comment: Getting Run-Time 438 Object does not support method error on line `.SortRange Range("A1:D" & lngLast)`

Comment: @Jim ... make sure the line says `.SetRange` and not `.SortRange`