# Custom Sort of whole dataset over specified columns but variable rows

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort a large dataset with respect to 7 different columns. The columns range from 'A' all the way to 'AQ', but only the following (twenty-six) columns are visible: B, E, F, H, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, AB, AC, AD, AH, AI, AJ, AQ. The sorting of the rows over the whole dataset (including information in the hidden columns) is to be done with respect to columns H, K, L, Q, R, S, U. The sort order is to be A to Z', except U which is a Date Column with Format 'Custom d-mmm-yy', and should be sorted 'Oldest to Newest'). Note that column 'A' is hidden. Also worth noting is that columns F and AE, AF, AN, AO, AQ, are completely empty, but they need to be part of the whole dataset to be sorted. Also, some other columns are only partially filled. The row count has been kept variable, as it is to be applied to several files, all with different row counts.

I came up with the following code based on someone else's question about a related matter, but when I run it it does not seem to execute properly, as can be seen when the 'Sort' icon at the top of the screen is clicked - the Sort Order is not shown. Yet no error message appears. It seems that the code is not properly picking up the cells. What changes need to be made to the code?

```
Sub SortOrder()

Dim lngLast As Long
lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("data").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1:H" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K1:K" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("L1:L" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q1:Q" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("R1:R" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("S1:S" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("U1:U" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A1:AQ" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying the range `lngLast = Worksheets("data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: 'lngLast' is meant to automatically count the number of rows with respect to column 'A', just like in a previous example:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095053/sort-macro-with-dynamic-range-and-customorder-excel

Comment: Yes but you haven't specified which worksheet so the active sheet will be used which might not be 'data'

Comment: 'Worksheets("data").Sort' has now been prefixed with 'ActiveWorkbook'. But this still does not make any difference.

Comment: Have you changed the `lngLast=` line to what I suggested ?

Comment: Yes. I even tried the additional prefix of 'ActiveWorkbook' in the lngLast= line. What I have also noticed after running the Macro is that when a cell within the dataset is selected and the 'Sort' icon is clicked, the Sort Order does not show up. But instead if I place the cursor outside the dataset in the top-left corner and on the grey arrow pointing towards the bottom-right, and then click the 'Sort' icon, then the Sort Order does show up. Is there something about my Macro that is causing it to select all cells, and not the cells within the dataset itself?

Comment: Check the value of `lngLast` either with `debug.print lngLast` or `Msgbox lngLast`